# How to have a property for an array in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have a `UIButton` array.

```
UIButton *btn[12];
```

I want to set property for this btn.

How to do this. I tried

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIButton *btn;
```

with

```
@synthesize btn;
```

but it doesn works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSArray/NSMutableArray instead of primitive arrays, youll have a much easier time